# javafx chart dynamic multiple entity

Tags: reflection, javafx, combobox, getter, linechart

I want to create a JavaFx LineChart able to display data from entity class dynamically selected by the user through a combobox.
Since the number of entity and their attributes is big and could be change, I want to create this process in a flexible way without hardcode the combobox filling and a switch case state to select the proper get method.

Any suggestions on how I can manage this two operations? I'm thinking to something like an application.properties file and the use of reflection, but I didn't find the right solution.

thanks in advance

Comment: What is the source of the data? What are those `get` methods and how is the whole thing displayed as chart? We need that information to get an idea whether a certain approach would be appropriate here if it's just an "overkill".

Comment: I've several phisical devices attached to serial ports and I perform periodical monitoring on them.
Each device has an entity class where i store data of its attributes value.
I want to implement a single generic line chart where plot desired attribute of desired device selected by the user.